# how to use ffmpeg/libavcodec/libstagefright

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I just have a question about how to use `ffmpeg/libavcodec/libstagfright.cpp`: I try to `avcodec_open2(st->codec, codec)` when I have use ffmpeg to set `codec->id` as `CODEC_ID_H264,codec->name` as `libstagefright_h264`,that means I will open 
AVCodec `ff_libstagefright_h264_decoder`.

but when `Stagefright_init->OMXCodec::Create->configureCodec-> initOutputFormat(meta)`, the process just Quit ! It is a bazinga !

I knew that meta is Metadata, its data comes from `codec->extradata`, and in here, it means sps and pps, am I right?

How can I use `libstagefright` sucessfully in ffmpeg? Can somebody give me an example?

Comment: you may want to take a look at this project : http://gitorious.org/~olvaffe/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-android , in particular to http://gitorious.org/~olvaffe/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-android/trees/android/doc

Comment: have a look at it might helpful : <a href="http://code.metager.de/source/xref/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libstagefright.cpp">http://code.metager.de/source/xref/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libstagefright.cpp</a>

Answer (score 1):

It works at ICS4.0.3 ,Moto XT910,FFmpeg 0.7

I use extradata for store MediaFileName,then get metadata from  codes:

```
DataSource::RegisterDefaultSniffers();
sp<MediaSource> source ;
source = createSource((char*)MeidaFileName);
if(source==NULL){
    return -1 ;
}
meta = source->getFormat();
if(!meta->findData(kKeyAVCC, &type, &data, &data_size))
{
    return -1 ;
}
meta->setCString(kKeyMIMEType, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);
```

then you can `OMX::create`(there are some difference for  Android 2.3 and ICS)

Answer (score 1):

Im actually working on providing stagefright to my ffmpeg library on Android. I made some changes to original libstagefright.cpp from ffmpeg/libav but it is still not stable. After stabilizing it I will create pull request for ffmpeg/libav team. You can look around on my [project](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg):  in *"hwaccel"* branch.

It is available at *AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/ffstagefright.cpp* directory.

To use this library you have call standard ffmpeg methods and open insteed of standard h264 codec libstagefright_h264 codec:

```
AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name("libstagefright_h264");
```