# Encode NV21/YV12 in h264 in android low api

Tags: android, video, camera, h.264, encode

As discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458289/encoding-h-264-from-camera-with-android-mediacodec) topic I see how to encode camera preview frames in h264, however, it is done there using MediaCodec which is min API level 16(4.1 JB).
Is there any way to do the same thing in lower APIs, say (12 -3.1 Honeycomb or 8 -2.2 froyo) 
without using the MediaRecorder as been done by spydroid?

It is my first time here guys, so I am sorry if I did something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the lower level (and not officially public) Android multimedia API called stagefright. There has been an effort to wrap this API into ffmpeg, see e.g. [how to use ffmpeg/libavcodec/libstagefright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613436/how-to-use-ffmpeg-libavcodec-libstagefright)