# android hw h264 encoder (x264?) for ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, h.264, x264

I'm integrating ffmpeg into android, while found the h264 encoder is missing.
I looked around and seems it requires a x264 lib for that, but I'm not sure if x264 supports hw acceleration, or just a pure sw encoder? And is there any hw h264 encoder available for ffmpeg?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613436/how-to-use-ffmpeg-libavcodec-libstagefright and references therein.

Answer (score 1):

x264 is pure sw encoder.  For hw encode on android, you usually get OpenMAX IL libraries which can be used in native (ndk) code.  If it is android 4.1 or later, you also get MediaCodec java api, which calls OpenMAX.