# Getting frames from video and not with MediaMetadataRetriever

Tags: android, opencv, video, ffmpeg, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to find a way to extract video into frames.
The main goal is to change the image using openGl and construct the video again.

the problem is that I can't find a desent way to extract the video. I saw that lots of familiar questions were answered with the use of MediaMetadataRetriever but I don't want to use it because it works really slow.

I did a little research about libraries like - jcodec, ffmpeg ,openCV and mp4parser.

jcodec - works fine but really slow, every getFrame() costs 1 second.

ffmpeg - under GPL license which means that you'll have to publish your code.

openCV - complicated. Maybe I can accomplish what I need with it but it looks too complicate and I'm looking for a simpler solution.

mp4parser - extracts decoded frames but doesn't support encoding them to jpg/png.

Would be wonderful to get some help on that one. tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ffmpeg libraries are licensed with LGPL, and don't require opening all your code. The android build of avcodec include an interface to libstagefright, which provides hardware codecs for h264 (avc). This is as fast as you can get on Android.

Comment: part of the ffmpeg's libraries are under GPL and these are the one I need in order to decode the frames back to png(libx256). About the libstagefright - it sounds interesting, do you have maybe a source code, blog post or some other resource that contains more 'how to' info to share with the readers? Tnx

Comment: libx256 is for encoder, isn't it? Why do you need GPL then?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613436/how-to-use-ffmpeg-libavcodec-libstagefright